# Apply ICC profile 'on the fly' via PHP

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, dropzone.js, imagick, color-profile

I've made a dropzone.js that allows visitors (to my Wordpress hosted site) to upload a large image, which displays a thumbnail on successful upload.

I followed this handy guide (by @soderlind ) to begin with https://soderlind.no/dropzonejs-wordpress-rest-api/

I wonder if its possible to create a script to apply pre-defined ICC profiles to that thumbnail (not the original image). To emulate, for the visitor, different colour profiles.

The visitor should be shown a list of ICC Profile names, on selection they become active / applied to the thumbnail. On the same page, without reloading or navigating elsewhere.

I am no javascript genius. PHP code does exist to apply ICC profiles, see below, but displaying the desired selection "on the fly" is proving difficult for me.

Here's a script that uses Imagick (PHP) to add a profile to an image. via http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.profileimage.php

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick("CMYK_image.jpg"); // load image
$profiles = $image->getImageProfiles('*', false); // get profiles
$has_icc_profile = (array_search('icc', $profiles) !== false); // we're interested if ICC profile(s) exist

if ($has_icc_profile === false)
{
  // image does not have CMYK ICC profile, we add one
  $icc_cmyk = file_get_contents('/path/to/icc/SomeCMYKProfile.icc');
  $image->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
}

// Then we need to add RGB profile
$icc_rgb = file_get_contents('/path/to/icc/SomeRGBProfile.icc');
$image->profileImage('icc', $icc_rgb);

$image->setImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);

$image->writeImage("RGB_image.jpg");

?>
```

Any ideas?